# NodeJS 5 errors while installing npm packages

Tags: node.js, msbuild

Since I installed node 5.0.0, I start getting errors while installing most of npm packages.
it never happened before when I had node 4.x.

after

```html
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:116:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:71:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
```

basically there's 2 main errors.

- The first is asking for python.
- The second is asking for .Net SDK 2.0.

after getting python 2.7.10 installed the first error disappeared. but I couldn't pass the MSbuild.exe error even after installing .Net SDK.

Is this happening with everyone?
Do I have to install Visual Studio to get node.js and NPM to work?

I prefer not to. Any alternative way?

I tried a clean installation, restarted my PC and installed it again, same errors.

## Update

Now I installed both Python and VS2015, the previous errors are gone but I have this error

```html
c:\Users\Murhaf\Desktop\sage\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported projec
t "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the
path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\Users\Murhaf\Desktop\sage\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:bufferutil bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil Exit status 1
```

Comment: set the envoirment vairable with name "PYTHON" and then try

Comment: Try to run it in Cygwin. Building native addons on Windows is quite the hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need Visual Studio and Python to install modules with binary components on windows, which probably means the module you are trying to install has binary components, so try to install it after Visual studio and Python.

Comment: is Visual basic for free? do you know which version is required?

Comment: sorry, i meant visual studio, and yes there is a free version called visual studio express.

Comment: in addition to your answer, Widnows SDK feature in VS installer must be checked.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --msvs_version=2013` should work.

I am having problems with VS2015, too.